# Is there an easier way to refactor this in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

When I update the name of an object in the Object Inspector (e.g., `fruitsList: TListBox;` becomes `foodList: TListBox;`), is there way to have it update all references to it as well?

The events that are attached to this object are of course renamed appropriately, but I've got other references to it in the code that are not.

I'd like to correct things like this that are littered through the codebase I'm working on.

```
fruitsList.Enabled := FALSE;
```

Is this something I can do in one operation? Or am I stuck renaming it in the Object inspector, flipping over to the Code view, recreating the variable on the form, and then using Refactor->Rename to complete the task for the 47 references to fruitsList through the code?

Comment: I think your solution is the best option. Does the rename refactoring really not work with auto created vars?

Comment: You could go the other way. Use the refactoring command, and then edit the name in the DFM file.

Comment: @Rob That can work but you need to navigate the IDE's dialogs that attempt to clean up the dfm file for you by removing the entries for the control that doesn't exist any more. Text editor for the dfm is the usual way round this.

Comment: It works for me if I right-click the name in the form class declaration and do a name refactor. All references in the code and .dfm are updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the Rename refactor in the code editor on a control, it will rename all references in the code *and* rename the instance in the DFM file. Or at least it does in XE2.

Comment: My favorite refactoring in the Delphi IDE: seems to work since D2009 (no clumsy modeling support required)